# Shrink an element's height to match its parent using CSS

Tags: html, css, height

I'd like to shrink the height of one element to match its sibling's height; the siblings height is dynamic. Put another way I'd like to have one, variable height, element forced to shrink its height to fit the height its parent would have if the child was not there.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="shrunk_element">
        <span style="color: red;" >If I was really tall I sure wish I could shrink to match the height of my sibling</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sibling" style="width: 60%;">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/384x216/000/fff?text=variable+width+consistant+aspect+ratio" style="width: 100%;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a more complete but still non working as desired example http://jsfiddle.net/thisma/k3ngo1mg/3/
And here's an example that works but uses javascript and jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/thisma/k3ngo1mg/5/

Comment: In practice, wouldn't that be too similar to float:right?

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/f4smu6L3/

Comment: Floating an element does not decrease its size below its content's size, and doesn't change the size of any of its siblings. So I'm not sure how to implement float to solve this issue.
I just saw your second post. Here is an updated example showing that that doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/thisma/f4smu6L3/1/

Comment: Fair enough. Can jquery be involved?

Comment: In a working soloution the text should never go lower than the bottom of the image, and should have something like overflow-y: scroll; to show any hidden text.
Thank you for your quick response though.

Comment: No javascript. I've come up against this issue a few times now, and I already know how to solve it with jquery. I am looking for a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the parent position to relative, push the image to the right (using margin for example) and set the content to absolute with the top and bottom set to zero. Setting the top and bottom to zero will stretch the div to fit the parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/k3ngo1mg/7/

```
.parent {position:relative;}

.width_constraint {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left:40%; /* pushing the element to the right */
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.ratio_enforcer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
.fake_iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.matched_content {
    width:39%;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position:absolute; /* setting the element to absolute */
    top:0px;           /* and setting the height to fit the parent */
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
}
div {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```